# Exporting Mongoose code in Node.js - pass value to callback from Mongoose method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two JS files: `app.js` which has the HTTP API method handlers, and `model.js` which contains the Mongoose (MongoDB) methods, which will be called/consumed by the `app.js` HTTP methods.  Before, when I had all my code in one file (`app.js`) it was working perfectly. But when I split it to have Mongoose code separately then I had an error.

The website concept is, it displays a todo checklist, with the title of the list being `"Today's"` list. So in the database, there's a model `List`, which has a `name` field/property and an array of `items` (checklist items) field/property.

The idea is, when the website loads, the Home page displays `Today's` todo list. It does this by first checking in the Database, if there's a List object with the name `Today's` it renders it in the Home page, otherwise it creates this List object by calling methods in the `model.js` file, before rendering the Home page.

So the steps are:

1- In `app.js`, the `app.get('/' ...` method calls `List.findOne` Mongoose method in `model.js`, to check first if `Today's` List object exists in database.

2- If `List.findOne` finds `Today's` list object, I need to pass `Today's` list object to a `callback`, so that it can received in `app.get('/'...` method, which in turn will use it to render the Home page.

3- However, if `List.findOne` does not find `Today's` list object, then I need to pass something else back to the `callback` like a null, a string `"null"` or something to indicate that the List object `Today's` is not found. That way `app.get('/'...` method will receive something in the `callback` that indicate "list not found" and calls another Mongoose method to create `Today's` list object.

However, I'm just getting an error instead of being able to pass anything to the `callback`:

Error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started, listening on port: 3000
list not found
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at Function.createNewListInDB (C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\model.js:72:29)
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\app.js:22:23
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\model.js:38:17
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4849:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4849:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4872:21
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4379:11
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4851:13
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here's my code:

`model.js:`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//create DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });


//create schema
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String
});

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
});


//create model (aka Collection) (equivalent to Table in SQL))
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);
const List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);


class DBUtility {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class DBUtility");
    }

    // *** DB utility methods

    static findOneList(listName, callBack) {

        List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
            } else if (!foundList) {
                console.log('list not found');
                const value = 'null'
                callBack(value);   
            } else {
                console.log(`found list.`);
                callBack(foundList)
            }
        });
    }

    static createNewListInDB(listName) {
        //create default items for new list
        const introItem = new Item({
            name: 'Welcome to your todolist!'
        });

        const addItem = new Item({
            name: 'Hit the + button to add a new item.'
        });

        const deleteItem = new Item({
            name: '<-- Hit this to delete an item.'
        });

        const listNameCap = _.capitalize(listName);
        const list = new List({
            name: listNameCap,
            items: [introItem, addItem, deleteItem]
        });
        list.save(err => {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(`List ${list} added successfully to DB.`);
        });
    }

}

exports.DBUtility = DBUtility;
```

`app.js:`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const date = require(`${__dirname}\\date.js`);
const model = require(`${__dirname}\\model.js`);
const ejs = require('ejs');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));


//*** HTTP requests handlers

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const defaultListName = "Today's";
  const todayFormatted = date.getDate();
  model.DBUtility.findOneList(defaultListName, (foundList) => {
    if (foundList === 'null') {
      model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName);
      res.redirect('/');
    } else { 
      res.render('list', {
        listTitlePassToH1: foundList.name,
        todayDate: todayFormatted,
        listItems: foundList.items
      });
    }
  });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started, listening on port: ${port}`);
```

I've looked at other similar posts on SO, and not sure if it's solving a similar issue to mine, but one post suggests using Promise on all Mongoose methods to ensure each operation is executed before moving to the next task. If this is the case for me, then I'm not quite sure how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to work but I have ran into this problem before. Try requiring lodash in your `model.js` file: `const _ = require("lodash");`.

Comment: Correction, actually that was part of the problem. The fact I was using a `lodash` api inside `static createNewListInDB` method and didn't even include `const _ = require("lodash");`. Silly error. The other issue was, inside `static findOneList` method, in order to pass the `foundList` value from the query result, even if no list was found, i.e. `null` was the value, to do this, I needed to create `var` inside the method, and initialise it to `null`. Then when I get `foundList` back from the query result, just assign it to the var. Then pass that var to the callback.

Comment: Even if the value of var stays `null`, the callback will be able to pass that value back without any issues. So you've solved part of my issue, and I'll mark your solution with a green tick :)

Comment: Well, the question wasn't about the second logic error, but I am happy that I was able to help you with the syntax error. Happy Coding!